# Suspected rounding error in solution to CodeWars Kata

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am attempting to solve [this kata on Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/heroes-of-might-and-magic-ii-one-on-one/train/javascript) using Javascript.

This kata requires you to pit 2 types of monsters from the game Heroes of Might and Magic 2 against each other, each taking turns to attack each other until one comes out victorious.

Most of the tests are now successful, however I'm still getting a few errors that are 1 out from the expected result. e.g.:

> 'Expected: '5 Boar(s) won', instead got: '4 Boar(s) won'
>
> 'Expected: '1 Skeleton(s) won', instead got: '2 Skeleton(s) won'

The error is usually just out by 1 or 2, and seems to be in both directions (either my result is too high OR too low).

I've been fiddling around with my code quite a bit and can't seem to find the solution.

**Example monsters include:**

```
{ "type": "Roc",         "hitpoints": 40, "number": 6,  "damage":8 }
{ "type": "Unicorn",     "hitpoints": 40, "number": 4,  "damage":13}
{ "type": "Titan",       "hitpoints": 300,"number": 1,  "damage":50}
{ "type": "Battle Dwarf","hitpoints": 20, "number": 25, "damage":4 }
{ "type": "Paladin",     "hitpoints": 50, "number": 8 , "damage":20}
{ "type": "Skeleton",    "hitpoints": 4 , "number": 100,"damage":3 }
```

Unfortunately I can't see the stats of the monsters of the tests that are failing, so it's tricky to see where I might be going wrong. Is anyone able to help out? (P.S. I know the code could be tidier, sorry)

```js
function whoWouldWin(mon1, mon2) {
  var hitpoints1 = mon1.hitpoints * mon1.number;
  var hitpoints2 = mon2.hitpoints * mon2.number;

  function attack() {
    damage1 = (mon1.number * mon1.damage);
    hitpoints2 -= damage1;

    if (hitpoints2 < ((mon2.number - 1) * mon2.hitpoints)) {
      mon2.number = Math.ceil(hitpoints2 / mon2.hitpoints);
    }

    if (mon2.number <= 0) {
      return (mon1.number + " " + mon1.type + "(s) won");

    } else {
      damage2 = (mon2.number * mon2.damage);
      hitpoints1 -= damage2;

      if (hitpoints1 < ((mon1.number - 1) * mon1.hitpoints)) {
        mon1.number = Math.ceil(hitpoints1 / mon1.hitpoints);
      }

    }
    if (mon1.number <= 0) {
      return (mon2.number + " " + mon2.type + "(s) won");

    } else {
      return (attack());
    }
  }
  return (attack());
}
```

Comment: Move `mon1.number = Math.ceil(hitpoints1 / mon1.hitpoints)` outside the `if`

Answer (score 0):

```
hitpoints2 < ((mon2.number - 1) * mon2.hitpoints)) {
```

This is saying: If hitpoints2 is less than (number of monsters remaining -1 monster)  multiplied with full hitpoints for each monster,  calculate remaining monsters number.

But the last monster doesn't have a full hitpoint after a battle.